# No results message using display templates

Tags: sharepoint-2013, display-templates

I have a sharepoint 2013 site with a page that uses the CSWP and a custom display template.  When there are no results, I want to display a message that says "Share What's Going On".  I tried setting the $noResults variable in the display template, but nothing displays.  When I set a breakpoint on that same line, the browser doesn't break.

How do I display a "no results" message?

Thanks

Jim

Comment: Show your custom display template code if you want help...

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to set the EmptyMessage web part property value. The property is hidden so you'll have to set it programmatically or by exporting the web part and editing the .webpart file.

Think this link have your answer:
[Link for changing $noResults](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/74589/how-do-you-set-the-default-empty-text-with-the-content-by-search-webpart)